# How to change kind of UIStoryboardSegue based on traits

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue

Depending on the device type, I would like to either push a view controller onto a navigation controller stack, or present it as a popover.

Is it possible to add a customization to the kind property of UIStoryboardSegue in a storyboard based on traits?

I would like to use a segue for this rather than programatically presenting the view controllers. But I'm unable to figure out if that is possible. I tried subclassing UIStoryboardSegue, but I don't know how to programatically change the kind property.

Comment: You would need two different segues and then you would need to trigger the appropriate segue programmatically, deterring which at runtime based on the traits.

Comment: Thanks. That did work. (Would have loved to do it within a storyboard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paulw11's answer works: Use two manual segues. Then programatically call them when a button gets pressed.

It still seems odd that there is no way to do this in interface builder itself.